# Modal showing black backdrop in React

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu, modal-dialog, semantic-ui

I  am a newbie  in React and I am facing the following  behavior:
I have a page with a list of DropDown menus for which I want to show a Modal each time user tries to change the value.

However, when I follow the typical tutorials using a button trigger, everything works as expected:
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlc5O.png)

But when I simply try to just show the dialog without trigger or triggered by the droppDown menu, the backdrop is always black, like [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6mwz.png)

Here is my code:

```js
const styleLink = document.createElement("link");
styleLink.rel = "stylesheet";
styleLink.href = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui/dist/semantic.min.css";
document.head.appendChild(styleLink);

const options = [
  { key: 'Online', text: 'Online', value: 1 },
  { key: 'Offline', text: 'Offline', value: 2 },
];

class TicketAlocation extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
   
    this.state = {
      items: [],
      userStatus:[],
      options:[],
      value: '',
      show:false,
    };
   
     this.itemRenderer = this.itemRenderer.bind(this);  
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let context = this;
  }

  handleFieldChange = () => {
    this.setState({ show:true });
  };

   setConfirm = () => {
    this.setState({ show:false});
  };

  setCancel = () => {
    this.setState({ show:false});
  }
 
  itemRenderer(items, index) {
    var value = this.state;
    return (
      <>
        <div className="item">
          <p className="email">{this.state.items[index].email}</p>
          <p className="status">{this.state.items[index].isOnline}</p>
          <div className="small" > 
            <Row>
            <Col md={3} xl={2}>  
            <Dropdown
              onChange={this.handleFieldChange}
              options={options}
              placeholder={this.state.items[index].isOnline}
              selection
              value={value}
              item={this.state.items[index]}
            />
            </Col>
            </Row> 
          </div> 
          <Modal
            trigger={<Button>Show Modal</Button>}
            //open={this.state.show}
            // open={true}
            //onClose={this.setCancel}
            size={"tiny"}
            header='Reminder!'
            content='Call Benjamin regarding the reports.'
            actions={['Snooze', { key: 'done', content: 'Done', positive: true }]}
          />
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }

render() {
 
  const items = this.state.items;
  return (
    <div>
    <h1>Text</h1>
    <p>
      <a href="https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-list-drag-and-drop">
        <img
          alt="npm install react-list-drag-and-drop"
          src="https://nodei.co/npm/react-list-drag-and-drop.png?mini=true"
        />
      </a>
    </p>
    <Row>
      <Col md={6} xl={3}>
      <ReactList
        cssClasses="example"
         items={items}
         itemRenderer={this.itemRenderer}
         length={this.state.items.length}
       />
       </Col>
    </Row>
  </div>
  );
}
}
```

Could someone explain to me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What happens when you remove trigger={<Button>Show Modal</Button>} and put open={this.state.show} ?

Comment: backdrop becomes automatically black. The only desired output is when I use the button trigger.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by  moving  the Modal component into render, as before it was in itemRenderer.